# How to change the pitch and volume of MIDI note in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, midi

I use the following code in my project to play midi note on key press (this is midi-related part of source):

```
uses
MMSystem;

var
hMidi, midimsg, notenum, instrumNum :integer;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  midiOutOpen(@hmidi, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  midimsg := $C0+$100*29; // set midi instrument to overdriven guitar (29th in GM midi instrument list)
  midiOutShortMsg (hmidi, midimsg);
end;

procedure playNote(var note:integer);
begin
  midimsg := $90 + (note * $100) + (127 * $10000) + 0;
  midiOutShortMsg (hmidi, midimsg);
end;

procedure stopNote(var note:integer);
begin
  midimsg := $80 + (note * $100) + 0 ;
  midiOutShortMsg (hmidi, midimsg);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  playNote(60);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  stopNote(60);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var CloseAction: TCloseAction);
begin
  midiOutClose(hmidi);
end;
```

I know that there are midi messages to change the pitch and volume. But I could not find any examples of their usage in delphi. 
Please, help me to modify the *playNote* procedure to make sound similar to guitar bend effect (smooth pitch shift of played note on semitone or whole tone up) and similarly to change the volume of note (fade-in and fade-out effect).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have worked some with MIDI and Delphi, but I am not a musician, and I only know the basics. For instance, I know how to play a given note with a given 'volume' (called 'velocity', IIRC). I am a bit surprised that your `PlayNote` only accepts the tone and not the 'velocity'. [In addition, I use `NoteOn` and `NoteOff`, since some instruments need the note to be turned off manually...]

Comment: My `PlayNote` procedure is very simple demonstration. The velocity is set as 127. And I use `StopNote` to turn off note. You can see it in form's `onKeyUp` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
const
  MIDI_NOTE_ON = $90;
  MIDI_NOTE_OFF = $80;
  MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT = $C0;
  MIDI_PITCH_BEND = $E0;

function MIDIEncodeMessage(Msg, Param1, Param2: byte): integer;
begin
  result := Msg + (Param1 shl 8) + (Param2 shl 16);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  midiOutClose(hMidi);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  playing := false;
  midiOutOpen(@hMidi, 0, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
  midiOutShortMsg(hMidi, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT, 19, 0));
end;

procedure TForm4.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if playing then Exit;
  ProgressBar1.Position := $2000;
  midiOutShortMsg(hMidi, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_PITCH_BEND,
    lo(ProgressBar1.Position), hi(ProgressBar1.Position)));
  midiOutShortMsg(hMidi, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_ON, 50, 127));
  playing := true;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(hMidi, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_OFF, 50, 127));
  playing := false;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ProgressBar1.StepBy(4*WheelDelta);
  midiOutShortMsg(hMidi, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_PITCH_BEND,
    lo(ProgressBar1.Position), hi(ProgressBar1.Position)));
end;
```

Drop a `TProgressBar` on the form, and set its `Min` and `Max` to `0` and `16383`, respectively.

Then you can 'bend' the pitch by scrolling your mouse wheel. (Notice that the factor 4 I use when handling the mouse wheel might be unsuitable for your mouse and your current mouse settings.)

Sample: [pitchbend.exe](http://privat.rejbrand.se/pitchbend.exe) [I removed the EXE file from my website because Google Chrome considered it to be a malware. Although this was almost certainly a false positive, I was afraid that it would have a negative effect on my Google rankings.]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need to work with pitch. What about fade-out (-in) effect? Is it possible to change the velocity of separate note while it is playing? I did not find any information about midi message similar to  pitch bend that can regulate velocity..

Comment: @VIK: Velocity is a one-off value sent at the start of the note. However "Control Change" messages can be sent continuously. "Control Change" #7 is reserved for volume changes. See David's MIDI Spec for an easy to read reference. http://www.srm.com/qtma/davidsmidispec.html

Comment: Cool. I didn't know it was so easy to use Midi in Windows.

Comment: @Andreas: it even works with my magic mouse (which has no wheel, but a touchpad-like surface) in W7 in Parallels on a Mac! Although the pitch bends down if I move my fingers up and vice versa. Only a minor inconvenience. Love it.

Comment: @Rudy: Well, I am not a musician, so I couldn't know about that! ;)

Comment: @Andreas: I'm not a musician either (but in the past, I did build synths and other musical equipment), and it might work better with a real scrollwheel. Can't test that.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [pitch bend message](http://tomscarff.110mb.com/midi_analyser/pitch_bend.htm).

First four bits are `1110` and the next four indentify the channel.  The next two bytes are MSB and LSB for a 14-bit pitch bend value.  (First bit is always `0`.)

The "center" value of the pitch bend stick is 8192.

For example, lowest bend point on channel one:

```
11100000 00000000 00000000
```

How much the pitch goes up and down is entirely up to the synthesizer.  Many synths support [changing this range with an RPN](http://tomscarff.110mb.com/midi_analyser/pitch_bend.htm), but not all.